# Particle Acceleration

Tags: calculus

A particle moves along the x-axis so that its velocity at time t, when t is in between and equal to 0 and 6, is given by v(t)=4 sin (t^2/2 - 2t + 2).  At time t=0, the particle is at x=1.

Is the speed of the particle increasing or decreasing at time x=4?  State a reason for your answer.

Comment: you can find $v'(4)$ if $v'(4)>0$ then $v(t)$ is increasing.

Comment: @AsdrubalBeltran $v'(4)$ gives the acceleration at $t=4$, not $x=4$

Comment: @apetiss but then, because the question say in the time $x=4$, but not say in position $x=4$?

Comment: @AsdrubalBeltran I read the question as "find the acceleration at position $x=4$", else the initial condition $x(0)=1$ is totally irrelevant, no? I also assume it would say "time $t=4$" if we were to solve $v'(4)$. The wording is pretty bad, I agree.

Comment: @apetiss yes i now understand, but then solve the integral is dificult.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use the connection between position $x(t)$, velocity $v(t)$ and acceleration $a(t)$  $x(t) = \int_0^t v(t) {d}t $ with the integration constant in this case being $x(0) = 1$, similarly $a(t) = v'(t)$

You can use this information to solve for time when $x(t) = 4$. If $a(t)>0$ at that time, the velocity of the particle is increasing.